# space in between <pre> tag and Paper

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have some React code that generates an empty space in between my pre tag and the bottom of my Paper component. I can't figure out how to remove it.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  paper: {
    border: "1px solid"
    padding: "0px",
    margin: "0px",
    "margin-bottom": "0px"
  }
});
```

and:

```
 <Paper className={this.props.classes.paper}>
     <pre>Stuff</pre>
 </Paper>
```

I solved it by adding:

```
<pre style={{ margin: "0px" }}>
```

Comment: might be vertical-align to reset on pre since it behaves as an inline-boxe.

Comment: Wild (probably incorrect) guess, try removing the new line and spaces around the `<pre>`.

Answer (score 1):

I inspected the pre tag and noticed a margin. I solved it by adding:

```
<pre style={{ margin: "0px" }}>
```